# Pip installs old version of package

Tags: python, pip, version

Pip installs old version of my package

```
$ pip install pywps
Collecting pywps
    Downloading pywps-3.2.6.tar.gz (123kB)
...
```

If you go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywps/ the version 3.2.6 is not even mentioned there.

It's only mentioned at https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywps/

Any idea, why 3.2.6 is prefered over 4.0.0?

Thanks

P.S. Older responses do not seem to apply to this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the command with a verbose option (and an up to date [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)), you can see what's happening.

```
pip install -v pywps
```

It gives the following output:

```
  1 location(s) to search for versions of pywps:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywps/
  ...
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/f9/93/5c2c4c95e53b6193bf239ecc49cb859fd77d181311145edd13ba4cd39e09/pywps-4.0.0-py3.5.egg#md5=338eb2e56a36abc684800961b7e4ee0a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywps/); unsupported archive format: .egg
  ...
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/c8/e6/8b88bc134f714f73e296466ab6b5b5a5ad96c44d35dcbcf41ccf9b76a283/pywps-3.2.6.tar.gz#md5=32bbbefacce633baa9147c74e4416c98 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywps/), version: 3.2.6
  Using version 3.2.6 (newest of versions: 3.2.6)
  "GET /packages/c8/e6/8b88bc134f714f73e296466ab6b5b5a5ad96c44d35dcbcf41ccf9b76a283/pywps-3.2.6.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 123280
  Downloading pywps-3.2.6.tar.gz (123kB)
```

The egg file is ignored because .egg files are [not supported](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/492) in pip. They [were supported](https://packaging.python.org/pip_easy_install/) by [easy_install](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html). I think the best solution is to start producing [wheel files](https://packaging.python.org/current/#packaging-tool-recommendations), which I think for pywps can be universal. If you also want to keep supporting the `easy_install` command, you can upload the `tar.gz` file or keep producing `eggs`.

Answer (score -1):

You can install version 4.0.0 via pip straight from github:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/geopython/pywps.git@master#egg=pywps
```

Comment: I know, how to install required version, I'm asking how to (if that is possible) install the later version by default the "fast way".

Comment: The output of the common `pip install pywps==4.0.0` will tell you that `3.2.6` is the only version available that way.